# converting EfficientDetD0 model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tflite

I need to convert this EfficientDetD0 model to tflite, the input model structure is :

```
./EfficientDetD0
    ./checkpoint
        ./checkpoint/checkpoint
        ./checkpoint/ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001
        ./checkpoint/ckpt-0.index
    ./saved_model
        ./saved_model/saved_model.pb
        ./saved_model/variables
        ./saved_model/variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001
        ./saved_model/variables/variables.index
    ./pipeline.config
```

I have try this python code but outputTensors size is not correct

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('./EfficientDetD0/saved_model')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

my question : what is the best away to convert EfficientDetD0 model to tflite with this folder structure above